# How to write this for Loop in swift 4

Tags: swift, for-loop

```
for var i=count-2; i>=0; --i
{
     if let nextControlPoint = firstControlPoints[i+1]
    {

        let controlPointX = (rhsArray[i].x.f - c[i] * nextControlPoint.x.f)/b[i]
        let controlPointY = (rhsArray[i].y.f - c[i] * nextControlPoint.y.f)/b[i]

    }

    z += 1

}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please post your code.

Comment: for i in 0..<count-2 where i>=0 {
                if let nextControlPoint = firstControlPoints[i+1] {
                    let controlPointX = (rhsArray[i].x.f - c[i] * nextControlPoint.x.f)/b[i]
                    let controlPointY = (rhsArray[i].y.f - c[i] * nextControlPoint.y.f)/b[i]
                    
                    firstControlPoints[i] = CGPoint(x: controlPointX, y: controlPointY)
                }
                z += 1
            }

Comment: https://www.weheartswift.com/loops/ refer this

Answer (score 3):

You can write something like this

```
if count > 1 {
    for i in (0...count-2).reversed() {
        print(i)
    }
}
```

> The IF statement is needed because we cannot create a range where the first element is lower than the last one.

Comment: Its work Thanks Mr.Luca Angeletti

Comment: **(0...count-2).reversed().forEach**